# Device with Telnet/SSH not responding, show error

Tags: perl, network-programming

Strange issue I am running into.  I have a few devices with Telnet/SSH issues.  When I run my script the results are saying the script was successful.  When debug is on I get the follow results..

```
  [ 0.012464] pr finding prompt
  [ 0.016593] tr creating Net::Telnet wrapper for telnet
  [ 0.017859] tr connecting with: telnet Host 10.xx.xx.xx Port 23
```

How could I add something to show a error if a promopt is not present or the connection times out?

Thanks

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

    use Net::Appliance::Session;

    $file = '1list';
    open (FH, "< $file") or die "Can't open $file for read: $!";
    my @ios_list = <FH>;
    close FH or die "Cannot close $file: $!";

    chomp(@ios_list);

    my $ios_username = 'xxxx';
    my $ios_password = 'xxxx';

    DEVICE:
    for my $ios_device_ip ( @ios_list ) {

            my @version_info;

            my $proto = shift;
            if (($proto == 43)||($proto == 44)){
                    $tran = "SSH";
                    $app="/usr/local/bin/ssh";
            }else{
                    $tran = "Telnet";
                    $app="/bin/telnet";
            }

            my $session_obj = Net::Appliance::Session->new(
                    host => $ios_device_ip,
                    transport => $tran,
                    personality => 'ios',
            );

    #interace

            eval {
                     # try to login to the ios device, ignoring host check
                    $session_obj->connect(
                    username => $ios_username,
                    password => $ios_password,
                    #SHKC => 0
            );

            # get our running config
            $session_obj->begin_privileged;
            $session_obj->cmd('conf t');
            $session_obj->cmd('aaa authorization config-commands');
            $session_obj->cmd('exit');
            $session_obj->end_privileged;
            $session_obj->cmd('write memory');
            # close down our session
            $session_obj->close;
            };

    #error check
            if ($@) {

         if ( UNIVERSAL::isa($@, 'Net::Appliance::Session::Exception') ) {

             # fault description from Net::Appliance::Session
             print "We had an error during our Telnet/SSH session to device  : $ios_devi
    ce_ip \n";
             print $@->message . " \n";

             # message from Net::Telnet
             print "Net::Telnet message : " . $@->errmsg . "\n";

             # last line of output from your appliance
             print "Last line of output from device : " . $@->lastline . "\n\n";

         }
         elsif (UNIVERSAL::isa($@, 'Net::Appliance::Session::Error') ) {

             # fault description from Net::Appliance::Session
             print "We had an issue during program execution to device : $ios_device_ip
    \n";
    #         print $@->message . " \n";

         }
         else {

             # we had some other error that wasn't a deliberately created exception
             print "We had an issue when accessing the device : $ios_device_ip \n";
             print "$ios_device_ip The reported error was : $@ \n";
         }

         next DEVICE;
     }

    print @version_info;
    print "$ios_device_ip ok \n";
    #end
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble connecting, it may help to check $@ after the eval as there may be an error you're ignoring.

```
#interace

        eval {
                 # try to login to the ios device, ignoring host check
                $session_obj->connect(
                username => $ios_username,
                password => $ios_password,
                #SHKC => 0
        );
```

It's also worth noting that this doesn't do anything:

```
     my $proto = shift;
     if (($proto == 43)||($proto == 44)){
           $tran = "SSH";
           $app="/usr/local/bin/ssh";
     }else{
```

`shift` is operating on `@_` which isn't populated, so `$proto` will always be `undef`.